# Tailwind autofill only works after class="" but does work after className="" for React.js

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have installed tailwind CSS intelliSense

Why does the autofill work after "class" but not "className" is that normal? Do I just use "class" with react then? Seems to work.

Thanks for any suggestions

package.json has:

`"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascript", "html": "HTML" }, "editor.quickSuggestions": { "strings": true }`

tailwind.config.js file I tried:
 `content: ["./pages/**/*.{html,js}", "./components/**/*.{html,js}"],`

and I tried from the website:

`content: [ "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", ],`